# Put result from promise into a variable (for dummies)

Tags: javascript, promise, exif

I'm using the excellent exifr library to read the create date from pngs. I'm looping through an array and adding data to a created marker on a map... but I'm stuck on promises!

This is what I want to do in each iteration of the loop.

```
exifr.parse(bottlefullurl, {xmp: true, tiff:false})
    .then(output => bottledate = output.CreateDate);

jmarker.jmarkerdatedata = bottledate;
```

Which of course returns undefined as the promise isn't complete. I can console log it so I know the library works.

```
exifr.parse(bottlefullurl, {xmp: true, tiff:false})
    .then(output => console.log(output.CreateDate));
```

The documentation is great but the examples all only console.log
https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr/blob/master/README.md

I've read some great answers on Stack Overflow like this one...
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

... and some articles and MDN docs but it's about three steps ahead of my current Javascript understanding (I can't write arrow functions).

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be one level dumber. I had been trying await and getting an error because I was adding my .js file using **type='text/javascript'** not **type=module**... so await wouldn't work! Doh.

So it was super simple after fixing that:

```
jmarker.jmarkerdatedata = await exifr.parse(bottlefullurl, {xmp: true, tiff:false})
.then(output => output.CreateDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

bottledate isn't in the scope of where you assign it, it lives in the scope of the arrow function you created

try this:

```
jmarker.jmarkerdatedata = exifr.parse(bottlefullurl, {xmp: true, tiff:false})
    .then(output => output.CreateDate);
```

Comment: Feels like one step closer, returned [object Promise] instead of [undefined]. I've got an onClick function on each of the markers. Might be easier to do it there but I'd love to do it in the loop.